# why $m(K + r) = m(K) \implies m(K)=0?$

Tags: measure-theory

I have some confusion in Rudin RCA

> Here is an outline of Rudin's proof(Theorem $2.22$):

> **Theorem $2.22$ (Rudin)**: If $A\subset \mathbb R$ and every subset of $A$ is Lebesgue measurable then $m(A) = 0$
> **Proof**: We shall use the fact that $\mathbb R$ is a group, relative to addition. Let $\mathbb Q$ be
> the subgroup that consists of the rational numbers, and let $E$ be a set that contains exactly one point from each coset of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$. Then $E$ has
> the following two properties:
> $(a)$ $(E + r) \cap (E + s) = \varnothing$ if $r \in \mathbb Q$, $s\in\mathbb Q$, $r\neq s$.
> $(b)$ Every $x \in\mathbb R$ lies in $E + r$ for some $r \in\mathbb Q$.
> To prove $(a)$, suppose $x \in (E+r)\cap (E+s)$. Then $x = y + r = z + s$ for some $y\in E, z\in E,y\ne z$. But $y-z = s-r\in\mathbb Q$, so that $y$ and $z$ lie in the same coset of $\mathbb Q$,  a contradiction.

> To prove $(b)$, let $y$ be the point of $E$ that lies in the same coset as $x$, put $r = x - y$.
> Fix $t\in \mathbb Q$, for the moment, and put $A_t = A \cap (E+t)$. By hypothesis, $A_t$ is measurable. Let $K\subset A_t$ be compact, let $H$ be the union of the translates $K + r$, where $r$ ranges over $\mathbb Q \cap [0, 1]$. Then $H$ is bounded, hence $m(H) < \infty$.
> Since $K \subset E + t$, (a) shows that the sets $K + r$ are pairwise disjoint. Thus $m(H) = \sum_r m(K + r)$. But $m(K + r) = m(K)$. **It follows that $m(K) = 0$**. This holds for every compact $K \subset A_t$. Hence $m(A_t) = 0$. Finally, (b) shows that $A = \bigcup A_t$ where $t$ ranges over $\mathbb Q$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is countable, we conclude that $m(A) = 0$.

**My confusion**:  why $m(K + r) = m(K) \implies m(K)=0?$

**My attempt** : $K +{r}= \{a+r : a \in K\}=(a+r,b+r)$

so $m(K+r)= b+r-(a+r)=b-a$

Now take $a=0$ and $b=1$,then $m(K+r)=1-0=1=m(K)$

$\implies m(K)=1\neq0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember you have $\infty>m(H)=\sum_rm(K+r)$, and now using $m(K+r)=m(K)$, we get $\sum_rm(K)<\infty$ and that is only possible if $m(K)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The **it follows that** in Rudin doesn't refer solely to the previous sentence. It is obviously wrong that $m(K+r) = m(K)$ implies that $m(K)=0$.

The **it follows that** follows from both $m(H) = \sum_r m(K + r)$ and $m(K+r) = m(K)$ as an infinite sum of non negative equal numbers can't be finite.

Comment: your blog is awsome ,  you're doing a  great work @mathcounterexamples.net